# Where is file:///android_asset/Resources pointing in Titanium?

Tags: android-emulator, titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-modules

I have a Titanium project and I'm trying to load the file `index.html` located here

-root 
----build 
----modules 
----platform 
----Resources 
------index.html

With the following code:

```
var htmlFile = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.resourcesDirectory, "index.html");
```

And I get the error

> The webpage at file:///android_asset/Resources/ could not be loaded because: 
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

So I'm wondering where should I put the index.html file? Do I have to create a new folder somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Hi i had the same problem and my solution is:

```
-app
---assets
**-----first.html** --> this is my local html page to call
---controllers
---styles
---views
```

in the

```
-app
---views
-----index.xml i am calling the local html like: 

<Alloy>
    <Window class="mainWin">
        <WebView id='indexView' url='/first.html' />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

I hope this helps